# Jackson always tries to instantiate an abstract base class

Tags: java, json, jackson, polymorphism

I'm trying to deserialize subclasses with Jackson and `@JsonTypeInfo`.

I have the following classes but Jackson always tries to instantiate the abstract base class Communication and thus fails.

```java
public class PartnerCommunication {
    private String addressType;

    @Embedded
    @JsonTypeInfo(
            use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
            include= JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY,
            property="addressType"
    )
    @JsonSubTypes({
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=Address.class, name="Address"),
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=Telephone.class, name="Telephone")
    })
    private Communication communication;
}
```

```java
public abstract class Communication {
}
```

```java
public class Telephone extends Communication {
     private String phone;
}
```

```java
public class Address extends Communication {
     private String street;
}
```

The json I'm trying to deserialize looks like this.

```json
{
    "addressType": "Address",
    "communication": {
        "street": "My street"
    }
}
```

If I misspell the type, then Jackson returns an error, saying the only valid types are Address and Telephone. So it does understand the hint, but apparently doesn't follow it completely.
Am I missing some configuration?

Comment: I think that the `@JsonSubTypes` annotation needs to be placed on the `Communication` class and not on the field

Comment: @Lino-Votedon'tsayThanks I just tested it. It doesn't change the behavior. Jackson still tries to instantiate the `Communication` class.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work after I updated my Spring Boot setup. I'm using `2.3.1.RELEASE` for the starter parent now.